# adding youtube to CCScene?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I know how to add youtube to a view.
but we are using a CCScene(cocos2d) and i need to open a youtube and play it ,from a scene.

how would i do that ?

i know how to do it with adding a subview :

```
- (void)embedYouTube:(NSString*)url frame:(CGRect)frame {  
    NSString* embedHTML = @"\ 
    <html><head>\ 
    <style type=\"text/css\">\ 
    body {\ 
        background-color: transparent;\ 
    color: white;\ 
    }\ 
    </style>\ 
    </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\ 
    <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \ 
    width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\ 
    </body></html>";  
    NSString* html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, url, frame.size.width, frame.size.height];  

    if(videoView == nil) {  
        videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];  
        [self.view addSubview:videoView];  
    }  
    [videoView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];  
}
```

any help would be great .
thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector].openGLView addSubview:videoView];
```

If you're using cocos2d 2.0 the `openGLView` property is just called `view`.